# Laravel Auth attempt hashing

Tags: authentication, laravel, hash

In a login form, I have this Auth check:

```
$auth = Auth::attempt([
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
            'active' => 1
        ], $remember);
```

Now this Auth check is taking the raw input from the input field. Yet my database of which this is Authorising against stores the password in an encrypted state using Hash::make().

This login form works perfectly fine. The user logs in with the correct password, but it uses a raw password in the Auth function against a hashed password, yet returns true.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Auth class does the hashing in the background and compares the password the same way you would normally.

Comment: So would it be the best practice to not try hash the inputs into Auth?

Comment: Yes that is correct. As the password would then become a hash of a hash.